# Half-Face man in "Heaven"?

Tags: doctor-who

So, we all remember in the Doctor Who episode "Deep Breath" in series 8 with that weird half-face man. There was another question on the Stack Exchange about the scene of the half-face man's defeat, and that question inspired this question. So, we all know that the half-face man is a robot, so how could he go to heaven? That last scene showed him in this mysterious "Heaven" with Missy there, and even if it technically wasn't the real heaven, (rather a hard drive... thingy) how did the half-face man end up there if he was a robot? Being a robot, there was no form of spirit or even sentience that could render him in such a place. I know it was necessary to introduce that mysterious concept in the first episode, but couldn't they have introduced this "Heaven" in another, more realistic way? Possibly even by showing a citizen that was killed by the half-face man in heaven instead?

Comment: Thematically, part of the point of *Deep Breath* was that the Half-faced Man had replaced so many of his parts that he was more man than machine, and had developed a "soul" (of sorts)

Comment: I remember nothing. Who are you people.

Comment: If "heaven" is a "hard drive thingy," why couldn't a robot go there? That actually makes *more* sense than having people's minds go there.

Comment: @KSmarts Well, that really does make a lot of sense. xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Heaven wasn't actually Heaven (e.g. in the Christian sense of an other-worldly place filled with spirits and souls), it was actually a Time Lord storage device filled with the mind-states of the recently dead, recorded and captured using technology...

> by the **Master/Missy** as part of (what else?) an elaborate plot against the Doctor.

...

> **SEB:** *You're dead and, and this is what's next.*
>
> **DOCTOR:** *A Gallifreyan hard drive. Time Lord technology.*

That being the case, there seems to be no special restriction on a *robotic* intelligence being uploaded into the mind-sphere, any more than an *organic* intelligence can be uploaded.

Comment: That's a good point! By the way, how do you make that spoiler button? I would look at the HTML, but I'm on my mobile device right now.

Comment: @TheMinecraftMan757 - The spoiler tag is >! (with a space after it).